# Faster way to flatten list in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, flatten

I have a dataframe below:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({"terms" : [[['the', 'boy', 'and', 'the goat'],['a', 'girl', 'and', 'the cat']], [['fish', 'boy', 'with', 'the dog'],['when', 'girl', 'find', 'the mouse'], ['if', 'dog', 'see', 'the cat']]]})
```

My desired outcome is as follows:

```
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({"terms" : ['the boy  and the goat','a girl and the cat',  'fish boy with the dog','when girl find the mouse', 'if dog see the cat']})
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this without having to use a for loop to iterate through each row for each element and substring:

```
result = pandas.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df.terms.tolist())):
    x = df.terms.tolist()[i]
    for y in x:
        z = str(y).replace(",",'').replace("'",'').replace('[','').replace(']','')
        flattened = pandas.DataFrame({'flattened_term':[z]})
        result = result.append(flattened)

print(result)
```

Thank you.

Comment: For starters, **never append dataframes in a loop**. Accumulate your results in a list and concat them at the end.

Comment: i've got to ask, how did you ever end up with that first data-frame in the first place? If  you have lists in your data-frame, you probably shouldn't be using a data-frame at that point

Comment: DataFrame was provided from some source in that structure.

Comment: what does that even mean, 'from source'?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you should prob also tell him why he shouldn't append in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is certainly no way to avoid loops here, at least not implicitely. Pandas is not created to handle `list` objects as elements, it deals magnificently with numeric data, and pretty well with strings. In any case, your fundamental problem is that you are using `pd.Dataframe.append` in a loop, which is a quadratic time algorithm (the entire data-frame is re-created on each iteration). But you can probably just get away with the following, and it should be significantly faster:

```
>>> df
                                               terms
0  [[the, boy, and, the goat], [a, girl, and, the...
1  [[fish, boy, with, the dog], [when, girl, find...
>>> pandas.DataFrame([' '.join(term) for row in df.itertuples() for term in row.terms])
                          0
0      the boy and the goat
1        a girl and the cat
2     fish boy with the dog
3  when girl find the mouse
4        if dog see the cat
>>>
```